# flex windowedApplication skin - how to add close button

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, skinning

I am skinning WondowedApplication to get the following functionality:

- Close, Minimize, Maximise Buttons with custom skins of their own
- Setting and back button which change states in the main application
- Resizing bars on 4 sides and drag functionality

Can I achieve this by skinning WindowedApplication? If not how should I go about this?

I have resizing functionality already by default but not the drag functionality (I think it should work by default or not?).

Buttons also appear but they seem to loose their skin which is set by css (s:Button{...}), why is this? Also How could I access states of the skins host component (so I can exclude settings button from setting state for example)?

How can I access / add close,min,max buttons? I tried adding buttons but I can't use "this.nativeWindow.maximize();" as I couldi n host application.

Any help highly appreciated, I am very confused and annoyed with the lack of info on the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.minimize() and maximize() for minimize & maximize window and NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit() used for close window

Comment: thanks. hmmm, should have thought of that myself... Is that the best way of achieving this though? Also any ideas as to why the button skin wouldn't work inside windowedApplication's skin?